# Javascript objects help please

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an object called `$browser` within my javascript namespace which returns Internet Explorer version numbers based on feature detection.

I'm having trouble calling the function `ieVersion` within my object and have got the error `ieVersion is not defined`.

I can call `$browser.ieVersion()` outside the $`browser` object but not within.

what i'd like to be able to do is say ..

```
if($browser.ie6){
  // run my specific code...
}
```

Any pointers.....

UPDATE.... I've tried to follow the advice from Casablanca and have updated the code to reflect my interpretation of his changes.... I now have the error `Expected ':'` at `Namespace.$browser`

My Code....

```
// Namespace the functions to remove possibility of conflict.
var Namespace = {

    /// <summary>
    /// The browser object allows detection of ie versions.
    /// </summary>
    $browser: {

        ie6: Namespace.$browser.ieVersion() === 6,

        /// <summary>
        /// Uses feature detection to return the internet explorer browser number.
        /// </summary>
        ieVersion: function () {
            var $version = 0;
            // The browser is IE 6 - 8.
            if (!jQuery.support.leadingWhitespace) {

                // IE 6 & 7.
                if (!jQuery.support.boxModel) {
                    if (!jQuery.support.opacity && !window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        $version = 6;
                    }
                    else {
                        $version = 7;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $version = 8;
                }
            }
            return $version;
        }
    },

 Namespace.$browser.ie6 = Namespace.$browser.ieVersion() === 6;    

};
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits... reads much easier now.

Comment: Why would you downgrade feature detection to user agent sniffing?

Comment: I went to high school a very long time ago with a great trumpet player named James South.

Comment: @Pointy... Not me I'm afraid, guitar only in the key of stadium rock.

Comment: @ elusive..... I see what you mean but it'd basically be a quick and dirty test. If you look at the code I'm not looking at the user agent just feature detection tests that I know IE 6, 7 & 8 fail.

Comment: @James South: You are not looking at the user agent, but you are using your tests to simulate it. This does not make much sense, since feature detection is much more powerful.

Comment: Put this line: ` Namespace.$browser.ie6 = Namespace.$browser.ieVersion() === 6;` after that last `};` (assuming all other brackets are correctly nested).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with this line:

```
ie6: ieVersion() === 6
```

First, `ieVersion` by itself refers to the global (rather function-level) namespace. You need to fully qualify it as `Namespace.$browser.ieVersion`.

Second, `ieVersion` isn't defined yet. It is available only after the entire object has been created. You cannot refer to another function within the same object literal. Thus you can only initialize the `ie6` property after the entire object has been defined.

Put this line below the declaration of `Namespace`:

```
Namespace.$browser.ie6 = Namespace.$browser.ieVersion() === 6;
```

Comment: If I add the second line..  Namespace.$browser.ie6 = Namespace.$browser.ieVersion() === 6; I get an error Expected ':'

Comment: @James South: Where did you add this line? It should be outside and after the object declaration.

Comment: I've updated my code to reflect my interpretation of your suggestions.

Comment: @James South: It needs to be *outside* the entire declaration, after the closing `};` of `var Namespace`.

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that this line:

```
Namespace.$browser.ie6 = Namespace.$browser.ieVersion() === 6;
```

is not a valid property of your browser object, which is where you've put it.  It should have a `:` instead of an `=` (though the syntax would still be invalid since you can't namespace your property name) or it should be placed outside of the object declaration.

Also, you still have the exact same problem as mentioned by @casablanca earlier in the code -- even though you namespaced the code in your `ie6` property it's still referencing a function that doesn't exist yet.